# When I should use 'at' and when I should use 'in'?

Tags: prepositions

Here is a sentence by my friend. Can you help me identify which to use here?

> 1. I still remember the days of Kanya bhojan ( an event/festival where you serve food to all the ladies) in/at Lucknow.

Is it **in** or **at** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to cities, use 'in'

> I still remember the days.... **in** Lucknow.

When we talk about some 'place', 'at' is better.

> I still remember the days of Kanya Bhojan **at** Kaalimata Temple **in** Lucknow.

---

However, in India, small places like villages **may** take 'at' preposition. But as I said, they are the villages and **not** cities.

For instance, *moti khavdi* is a small village near Jamnagar City in India. I lived in that city for many years. When world's biggest refinery RIL was set many years back, in the news it used to be **'at moti khavdi'**. It has been decades now, but still I could find one such instance here -

> The RIL complex **at Moti Khavdi village** ***in*** Jamnagar is the largest oil refinery in the world. It is a high- security installation and is protected by the Central Industrial Security Force - [*Indian Express*](http://indianexpress.com/article/india/india-others/violence-in-jamnagar-ril-refinery-after-labourers-death/)

Comment: The actual place is Jabalpur. So, I was wondering whether I should say in Jabalpur or at Jabalpur ( M.P). I think it should be in Jabalpur because Jabalpur is not a village.

Comment: yes, [Jabalpur is a city](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jabalpur). So, *'...in Jabalpur*'.